# Format cell based on negative streak

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a habit tracker where I record the time spent on my habits on a daily basis (see screenshot below). I would like to highlight the name of the habit in red if the last three cells are 0. If I add a non-zero value after the streak (say on May 19th), the name cell should go back to the normal fill color. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with either a worksheet_change Macro, or conditional formatting.

For conditional formatting you want to add a new rule on Home -> Conditional formatting -> New rule.
Then select the last option, to use a formula.

Now all you need is a formula that checks the last three cells in the row, and evaluate if they are all 0 or not.

I'm not great with formulas, but I did manage to make one that seems to do the trick:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A2),LOOKUP(999,1/(B2:I2<>""),COLUMN(B2:I2)))),0,-2,1,3))=0
```

If you look at the ranges, you can see that this is meant for your "Read" row. But if you apply this rule to `A2`and then copy the formatting down to A3, a new rule should be created with updated references.

I tested it with this function, and also one that ends on `<>0` Making it green, here is the result:
[image]

**Function breakdown**

First I found a function to get the last non empty cell over at [exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell) and they can probably explain it better. I modified it to search for last column instead, and ended up with:
`LOOKUP(999,1/(B2:I2<>"",COLUMN(B2:I2))` Where "999" is just supposed to be bigger than any possible number in the range.
This returns the value of the last cell, and that's nice, but I need the last three values. I figured `OFFSET()` was an easy way to do this, but then `OFFSET()` needs a reference.

So I put the `LOOKUP()` inside an `ADDRESS()`, now it returns the cell address instead of value (*I put the row inside `ROW()` only so that it will update properly when copying the formula to a new row)*.
However, it does so as a string, which still doesn't work for `OFFSET()`, so I proceed to put the whole thing inside an `INDIRECT()`.
With `OFFSET()` I set it to stay on the same row, go back two columns, and then include 3 columns. You could just as well write it `,0,0,1,-3` instead of `,0,-2,1,3`.

Now it should technically return the values of the last three cells, but that doesn't work. So we use a `SUM()` to calculate the total value instead.